Are There Exchange Server Add-ins
I'm looking at Exchange add-ins and all I see are add-ins that run on Outlook clients.
Is there an option to create server side add-ins that will run on the exchange server itself? and if so, are they available for both on-premis and Online Exchange?

Exchange add-ins are typically designed to run on Outlook clients, but there are options for server-side functionality as well.
For on-premises Exchange and Exchange Online, you can use Exchange Web Services (EWS) or Exchange REST APIs to create server-side applications that interact with the Exchange server. These APIs allow you to perform various operations such as accessing mailboxes, sending emails, and managing calendar events directly on the server.
However, these are not traditional "add-ins" like those you see in Outlook clients. Instead, they are more like server-side applications or services that can interact with Exchange data.
For managing add-ins in Exchange Online, you can use the Centralized Deployment feature in the Microsoft 365 admin center. This allows administrators to deploy add-ins across the organization, ensuring they are available to all users.
